# Unable to validate url (getting 404 error) however it is working in browser

Tags: url, uri

Always returning 404 error, below is the code:

private static bool RemoteURLExists(string url)
{
try
{
//Creating the HttpWebRequest
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "Get";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36";
//request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36");
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
response.Close();
return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
ex.Message.ToString();
return false;
}
}

Comment: Please write your question clear so it will be understandable for developers. Please use proper code blocks to show your code so its readability will be better.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response, however i found the cause of this issue. Thanks again.